# Can you move files outside of a repository?

Tags: git-bash

A little context. I am doing an assignment that requires me to replace the placeholder index.html file with a login screen for my website. It is structured as so:

```
public.html
|   index.html
|   index.html.orig
|
|---dashboard(repository)
    |   dashboard.html
    |   index.html
    |   style.css
    |   README.md
```

This is what I've been trying to do:
`cd public_html/dashboard`
`git mv -f index.html ../`
and it gives me `fatal: '..' is outside repository`. I am at a loss for what to do and I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: you cannot move the file outside of git and have it handled by git anymore. however you can always simply copy the file by: cp index.html ../

Comment: or an even nicer solution would be to delete the index.html file inside the public.html directory and create a symlink to the file in your dashboard directory. 
i.e. "cd .. && rm index.html && ln -s dashboard/index.html index.html" that way the file in the public directory will be a pointer to the file in your git repository and always reflect that files state